# How long would it take for a U.S. dollar bill to rot?

Tags: internal-consistency, currency

So, in a post-apocalyptic scenario I’m working on, one of the main things is that at the time, there were people dumping their entire life savings out the window and into the street. They just didn’t want them anymore, money couldn’t help them in this scenario, and millions of dollar bills still litter the streets because no one else wanted them either.

My story is set 30-40 years after the initial event, and I’m having a character walking the ruins of a city. I want there to still be thousands of bills in the streets, but realistically, would they still be there after all that time, and not have rotted away or anything?

- No one has been going around collecting them, but they were probably stepped on for the first few years or so.
- There hasn’t been any major fires or attacks after the bills were dumped, so nothing has burned them all up or obscured them with rubble.
- There have been animals snooping around in the cities, and they’ve been exposed to the elements, wind, rain, snow, and the like.
- They’re sitting on top of asphalt and concrete instead of just dirt, so would this slow down the decomposition?

Edit: What if some of them were blown into corners, or under balconies and awnings? Would this protect them from the elements more? How much would the geographical location of the city matter, as in different climates effecting decomposition time?

Comment: No more piles of pre-war money lying around by that time.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but the US Bureau of Printing expects paper currency to survive about 18 months while in circulation before requiring it to be retired.  It expects coins to survive about 18 years in circulation before they must be retired.

Comment: If there was loose change as well as coins, would it still be recognizable? The metal would definitely survive, but would you still be able to make out the faces and denominations?

Comment: Uses of paper money, other than for currency, may include insulation or fuel for burning. Toilet paper, very poor clothing patches(*maybe layers of them would make a decent patch*), and other uses any fabric is capable of (*though it would require more work to use than most other alternatives, but might be used if those alternatives are unavailable*) My personal favorite is toilet paper. I would keep my wallet on me to easily carry that around.

Comment: The thought of bills as post-apocalyptic toilet paper is both hilarious and realistic. Imagine a former banker wiping with a roll of Benjamins.

Comment: other currencies (cad or eur for example) are printed on much more resilient paper, though.

Comment: That's interesting. What kind of other currencies? (Where in the world would they be used, I mean)

Comment: I'm not sure about the CAD, but I thought the EUR was essentially (a very tough & pliable) plastic.

Comment: The scenario doesn't sound very plausible.  Most people don't keep big bags o' money in their homes that can be dumped into the street like that.  You'd probably want to explain what was going on before the 'event' to explain the existence of all that paper money.

Comment: Well, in my mind it's kind of a "you can't take it with you" type thing. People see the world going to hell around them, and some of them just take their entire life savings, which is quickly becoming worthless, and try and donate it to charity. When the charities won't take anymore, they just get it all in cash, and chuck it out the window, in hopes that someone can still use it.

Comment: What is wrong with old-fashioned bottle caps? They never lose their value...

Comment: @possiblySerious: A growing distrust of banks would be a simple reason to withdraw your funds as cash and stuff it under your mattress.  A real-life example was the run on banks when Cyprus announced that it was freezing everyone's assets and was going to tax them heavily.

Comment: For what its worth, if everyone threw their life savings of dollar bills into the streets there would be _billions_ of bills out there. See [here](http://www.federalreserve.gov/paymentsystems/coin_currcircvolume.htm).

Comment: Also, if things really got that bad people probably wouldn't throw away their money, they would probably use it as material, sort of like post WWI Germany: http://rarehistoricalphotos.com/children-playing-stacks-hyperinflated-currency-weimar-republic-1922/

Comment: Well, it probably wouldn't be _everyone_, just some percentage. And there'd be bills of larger denominations than just singles.

Comment: Didn't read through all the comments, but one option would be changing the setting to a country which uses plastic bills. The only one I know of the top of my head is Romania, but that's quite an easy way to achieve what you want.

Comment: The GBP is printed on linen not paper

Comment: @Jim2B: CAD is plastic (you can deduce it from the transparent windows) but EUR is cotton.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**The bills would be gone or decomposed - *if they were simply left in the streets.***

As soon as the cities are abandoned animals and nature will reclaim the area. There are plenty of post-apocalyptic movies and video-games that will give you a great idea of how an urban area might look after a decade or more of complete abandonment.

Consider what would have happened in that time:

**Weather**

The bills would be swept up by the wind, rained on over and over again, frozen and defrosted, as well as baked in the sun.

**Animals**

Many animals would use bills as materials to construct their nests. That might only account for a small amount of them going missing, but it would still take a toll.

Other critters such as rats might just straight up *eat* them.

**Decomposition**

US currency is made out of organic materials, such as linen and cotton. These can and *will* decompose, be affected by fungi, etc.

**Inside Buildings**

Indoors, however, the situation might be rather different. Imagine your character entering a massive, ornate building which was once a major bank. The door had been sealed until he broke his way in, more than a decade after the cataclysmic event which caused the city to be abandoned.

Inside, money is strewn among the decomposed corpses of bank employees, rioters, and security personnel. From his books your explorer recognizes police uniforms, formal suits and ties, and, of course, rusted assault rifles.

The money they fought over in those moments of madness litters the floor, slightly moldy, but still completely recognizable in the dry, sealed environment of the bank which had gone on a security lock-down as the world went to hell around it.

Comment: I like the idea of animals using dollar bills as nesting material

Comment: I wonder why the assault rifles are rusted given that they were stored in a dry, sealed environment?

Comment: @GaryWalker They obviously rusted because of the blood and sweat and other bodily fluids of the corpses that lie next to the rifles. ;)

Comment: "There are plenty of post-apocalyptic movies and video-games that will give you a great idea of how an urban area might look after a decade or more of complete abandonment." Forget movies and video games. Here's an example in real life: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DWnjcSo9J0

Comment: You just gotta love Chernobyl. :)

Comment: @Ajedi32 30 years has done less than I would expect.

Answer (score 25):

The real-life [D.B. Cooper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._B._Cooper#Physical_evidence) case gives us some indication that we could possibly extrapolate from.  About eight years after the original skyjacking incident, some of the ransom money was found on the banks of a river near where Cooper might have landed.  It was in very poor condition, but still recognizable- enough for the FBI to link it to Cooper.

After eight years amongst mud and water some bills were nothing but brittle sheets of mold, while others look almost intact, maybe even enough to be accepted by a store clerk.  However, I suspect the better preserved bills were those on the *inside* of the bundles, while those nearer the top and bottom fared much worse.

In your scenario, the exposure duration is multiplied by three or four, and the bills are loose and not in bundles.  Extrapolation always requires a little conjecture, but I agree that nothing that could still be identified as a bill would remain.

Comment: [Mandatory relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1400/)

Comment: @Whaaaaaat I'm both surprised and delighted that there is actually a relevant XKCD for this.

Answer (score 16):

### It's unlikely anything would be left.

US currency is made of [paper composed of 75% cotton and 25% linen](http://www.bep.gov/hmimpaperandink.html), with a [thickness of 0.11 mm](http://papermoneyguide.com/faq.htm#52).  I haven't found any information that the paper is pre-treated with any sort of fungicide that would limit degradation.  So, you can consider them as ***very thin* strips of rags, composed of organic fibers**.  The wear and tear from the elements, combined with mold, would have almost certainly destroyed them after a period of several decades.

[image: a molding $10 bill]

Other countries use [polymer banknotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_banknote), which would be more resilient to weathering, although alternating temperature extremes might still eventually do them in.

Comment: Would cold make a large difference for mold? For instance, if it were a city in Alaska? and they were blown into corners or sheltered areas?

Comment: You'd have to go well north of alaska to get somewhere that it never thawed, and the constant thaw/freeze cycles will still make your bills soggy and weak.. And a good storm blowing on a soggy bill that is partially frozen to the ground is almost certain to wind up tearing it apart. Think of a soaking wet piece of paper that you hold by a corner out the car window - you'll be left holding just the corner. And molds / lichens / nesting critters still exist in Alaska too.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton: currency holds up better when wet than paper.  You can literally wash US currency in a washing machine without serious damage.  I saw this done on an episode of Candid Camera.  (The joke was they went to a laundromat and asked if they could "launder the money", but they meant in a literal sense.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes - granted the sort of fiber used in currency is more resilient than note paper - but the OPs premise is about a span of decades, and even cotton fiber is unlikely to withstand that long in exposed elements. Now a bunch of bills that found themselves encased in ice for 30 years might survive, but summer does come to Alaska too...

Comment: @MichaelBroughton: I should have added that I think the conclusion is correct, that the fabric US currency is made from won't survive that long.  The point about having one side frozen to the ground while the wind whips at it is a good idea for high stress.  It wouldn't break down as quickly as paper, and for somewhat different micro-scale reasons / mechanisms, but it would still break down.

Comment: *Here's what money is made out of; decide for yourself* is a much better answer then *well, it depends...*

Comment: I'm now wondering whether [monopoly money may outlast US currency](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/what-material-is-monopoly-money-made-out-of)